# Phonegap and web api

Tags: azure, cordova, asp.net-web-api

Hello I'm making my first phonegap application and I'm interesting in using a shared database (sql server?) and not the local storage that each platform has and phonegap supports.

I prefer the use of sql server because I used to work with it on my intranet job app. I was wondering if it is possible to use web api over php requests and manipulate my data with it (INSERTS, UPDATES and so on). I also think I should use standart rdbms cus I'm willing to use a daily job on the data.

So, will it be possible to make Web api requests using js on the phonegap app ?
Another question is if there is any way to test my web api proj on my mobile? thus I need to have any free trial web hosting provider (azure? or any cloud service?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

of course it possible! And it's amazingly simple. Your web API will handle all the stuff relating to the database (sql request...etc), then from your cordova app you will just have to make a http request on your webservices (using JavaScript) and get the result back in your JS callback in JSON (really easy to parse in JS).
I would suggest you to use an UI framework (suck as senchaTouch, JQueryUI...etc), those frameworks includes a "store" system that make httpRequest and items management really easy and transparent.

Hope I help!

Comment: Sounds great! What about the web hosting provider thingy?

Comment: If you wanna test it on a real device or on an emulator, I think that the only solution is to put your API on a real server. Then you can get a free trial provider or make you own computer as a server. If it is not necessary to test on a real device, I would suggest you to take a look at Ripple, a google-chrome pluggin that allows you to simulate a device on your navigator. Then you should be able to test on your localhost server. (I'm not sure that I understand correctly your question, do not hesitate if I'm wrong :) )

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if you think it's correct ;)

Answer (score 0):

There are frameworks like BreezeJS and JayData to abstract your database so you get a client side (javascript) view of your database. This is how it works

1. Expose your backend database (datacontext/dto context) as a WebAPI (good with BreezeJS) or OData (good with JayData)
2. Use the tools provided by these frameworks to generate client side view of your backend data which you can readily use.

Going by this route saves you from

- Writing javascript models of your backend data
- Writing js code to handle transportation data
- Plus you get nice query support, bulk data update for conserving network usage on mobile devices, if you need you get offline data as this is mostly required for mobile devices.

In my understanding these frameworks help you reduce your development cost, if your data access is mainly CRUD based. If you need to support more action based interaction, rather than REST, you may still do quite a bit of dev. which again may be less effort then not going for these frameworks.